# Is it possible to implement interaction pybox2d and pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, box2d

I'm writing a `Tetris` game on `Pygame`, but the pieces should crumble into sand after touching the floor or sand from other pieces. I did it through `pymunk`, but did not find a single article about the interaction of `pymunk` objects (sand) and sprites (falling figures).

The falling figures were made through *pygame sprites*, the sand was made through *box2d objects*.
Tell me how to track when a sprite comes into contact with a `box2d` object?

Sand spawns as *dynamic bodies* in the shape of a circle and has `type <class 'Box2D.Box2D.b2Fixture'>`

**So, how to track the touch of <class 'Box2D.Box2D.b2Fixture'> and the `pygame` sprite**

```
import pygame
from Box2D.b2 import world, polygonShape, circleShape, staticBody, dynamicBody
import sys, os

PPM = 4.0
TARGET_FPS = 60
TIME_STEP = 1.0 / TARGET_FPS
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300, 600

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

world = world(gravity=(0, -1000))

# walls
ground_body = world.CreateStaticBody(position=(0, 0), shapes=polygonShape(box=(75, 1)))
left_body = world.CreateStaticBody(position=(75, 150), shapes=polygonShape(box=(1, 175)))
right_body = world.CreateStaticBody(position=(0, 150), shapes=polygonShape(box=(1, 175)))

# prepare image for pygame.sprite
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data/images', name)
    if not os.path.isfile(fullname):
        print(f"Файл с изображением '{fullname}' не найден")
        sys.exit()
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)

    if colorkey is not None:
        image = image.convert()
        if colorkey == -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    else:
        image = image.convert_alpha()

    return image

# sprite
class SomeFigure(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = load_image("T_blue.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = 100, 30

        self.figures_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.figures_sprites.add(self)
    
    def render(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
        self.figures_sprites.draw(screen)

figure = SomeFigure()


def create_circles(pos):
    x, y = pos[0] // 4, (600 - pos[1]) // 4
    for step_y in range(0, 60, 16):
        step_y = -step_y // 4
        for step_x in range(0, 60, 16):
            print(x + step_x, y + step_y)
            step_x = step_x // 4
            body = world.CreateDynamicBody(position=(x + step_x, y + step_y))
            circle = body.CreateCircleFixture(radius=1, density=1, friction=1)
            print(type(circle))
        print()


def create_rectangles(pos):
    for step_y in range(0, 60, 15):
        for step_x in range(0, 60, 15):
            body = world.CreateDynamicBody(position=(pos[0] + step_x, pos[1] + step_y), angle=0)
            box = body.CreatePolygonFixture(box=(1, 1), density=1, friction=1)


colors = {staticBody: (255, 255, 255, 255),
          dynamicBody: (127, 127, 127, 127)
}


def my_draw_polygon(polygon, body, fixture):
    vertices = [(body.transform * v) * PPM for v in polygon.vertices]
    vertices = [(v[0], SCREEN_HEIGHT - v[1]) for v in vertices]
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, colors[body.type], vertices)


polygonShape.draw = my_draw_polygon


def my_draw_circle(circle, body, fixture):
    position = body.transform * circle.pos * PPM
    position = (position[0], SCREEN_HEIGHT - position[1])
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colors[body.type],
                       [int(x) for x in position], int(circle.radius * PPM))


circleShape.draw = my_draw_circle

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            create_circles(event.pos)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    for body in world.bodies:
        for fixture in body.fixtures:
            fixture.shape.draw(body, fixture)
    world.Step(TIME_STEP, 10, 10)
    figure.render()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(TARGET_FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a large box2d body with a square shape that will fit the unbroken piece. In this case, box2d will take on the job of searching for collisions between unbroken pieces and fragments of sand. All you have to do is link the sprite and this body.
If you want the body not to rotate use setFixedRotation() method.

If you don't want to create a separate body for the piece, it will be quite difficult for you to implement realistic interaction between the sand and
pieces (especially if the pieces move jerkily like in the original Tetris). However, you can use a simple search over all grains of sand, checking each one for intersections with the sprite. There are also more complex but more effective methods such as world queries for a given rectangular area (AABB queries)

Comment: The body moves evenly, so jerking should not cause problems. Regarding the solid box2d body, you will have to create polygons for the T and Г shapes at a minimum. In this case, you will still have to scatter them into the sand somehow, and not so that the whole figure falls on the sand and remains intact. The idea was initially to spawn a figure from tightly fitting balls, but when moving, they all need to change coordinates. If this can be done, it will be expensive and most likely with lags